# Why does an activity restart when I update a data in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-activity

My activity has a spinner of destinations, a MapView and a button. I'm trying to make the MapView shows my current Location when I select one of options of the spinner and click the button. Also, when I click the button, my current location and the destination selected should be updated in Firebase.
Firebase structure looks like this:
[Firebase Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onrSH.png)

Here is my onCreate method.

```java
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_student_home);

        requestPermission();

        // Construct a FusedLocationProviderClient.
        client = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        submitBtn = findViewById(R.id.studentDirectionSubmitBtn);
        submitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // Set destination spinner
                destinationSpinner = findViewById(R.id.studentDestinationSpinner);
                String destination = destinationSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

                // When nothing selected
                if (destination.equals("N/A")) {
                    Toast errorToastMessage = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "PLEASE SELECT YOUR DESTINATION", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    errorToastMessage.show();
                    return;
                }

                // Update current location and destination in Firebase
                mRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                extras = getIntent().getExtras();
                userID = extras.getString("userID");
                mRootRef.child("gtcp/user/student").child(userID).child("destination").setValue(destination);

                fetchLastLocation();

                Intent intent = new Intent(StudentHomeActivity.this, TrackingActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Here is fetchLastLocation method.

```java
    private void fetchLastLocation() {

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(StudentHomeActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Permission is not granted
            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(StudentHomeActivity.this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)) {
                // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setTitle("Required Location Permission")
                        .setMessage("You have to give this permission to access this feature")
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(StudentHomeActivity.this,
                                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        })
                        .create()
                        .show();
            } else {
                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(StudentHomeActivity.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);

                // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
                // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
                // result of the request.
            }
        } else {
            // Permission has already been granted
            client.getLastLocation()
                    .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                            if (location != null) {
                                Double latittude = location.getLatitude();
                                Double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                                LatLng ny = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                                googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(ny));

                                mRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                                extras = getIntent().getExtras();
                                userID = extras.getString("userID");
//                                mRootRef.child("gtcp/user/student").child(userID).child("currentLat").setValue(latittude);
//                                mRootRef.child("gtcp/user/student").child(userID).child("currentLng").setValue(longitude);
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    }
```

When I click the button, everything is updated correctly in Firebase, and it looks like moving to the TrackingActivity right after I click the button. However, after a few moments, it goes back to the previous activity, StudentHomeActivity where those codes are, again. Weird thing is it doesn't go back if I don't update anything. For example, if the user has destination of "A" and I choose A from the spinner and click the button, it doesn't go back.

Please help me out.

Comment: Instead of describing how you database looks like, please add a screenshot of it. Are you in some other parts of your code finish the activity? Do you have any errors?

Comment: @AlexMamo, I tried to add a screenshot, but I couldn't because my reputation is too low to upload it. And, what do you mean by "finish the activity"?

Comment: You can use [imgbb.com](https://imgbb.com/) to upload a picture. "finish the activity" meaning, are you calling `finish()` somewhere in your code?

Comment: @AlexMamo, I've posted a link of the screenshot somehow. And, no, I am not calling `finish()`method anywhere in whole project.